# Get the content of a paragraph that is inside a div that is inside a li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery I want to get the text of the paragraph class `.card__text` in the `div name="name"` (ie. `Rotten one`);

```html
<li id="d318" class="cards__item long">
  <div class="card long">
    <div name="nick" class="card__content long cell0">
      <p class="card__text">Johnny one</p>
    </div>
    <div name="name" class="card__content long cell1">
      <p class="card__text">Rotten one</p>
    </div>
    <div name="descr" class="card__content long cell2">
      <p class="card__text">One. This was a story of Johnny Rotten</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

I tried:

```
$("li#d318").first('.name').text();
$("li#d318").closest('.card__text').text();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the element directly using `#d318 .card__content.cell1`. Also note that `div` elements do not have a `name` attribute so your HTML is invalid. Those attributes should be removed. Try this:

```js
let text = $('#d318 .card__content.cell1').text().trim();
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="d318" class="cards__item long">
    <div class="card long">
      <div class="card__content long cell0">
        <p class="card__text">Johnny one</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content long cell1">
        <p class="card__text">Rotten one</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content long cell2">
        <p class="card__text">One. This was a story of Johnny Rotten</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> Thanks, but assuming I did not have those classes (`cell0`, `cell1`, `cell2`...), how would I go about it?

In that case you could use `:nth-child` like this:

```js
let text = $('#d318 .card__content:nth-child(2)').text().trim();
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="d318" class="cards__item long">
    <div class="card long">
      <div class="card__content long cell0">
        <p class="card__text">Johnny one</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content long cell1">
        <p class="card__text">Rotten one</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content long cell2">
        <p class="card__text">One. This was a story of Johnny Rotten</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, But assuming i did not have those classes cell0, cell1, cell2... how would I go about it?

Comment: In that case you could use `nth-child`. I updated the answer to show you how

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the 'name' attribute to create a unique div, I would change the 'cell0', 'cell1', and 'cell2' from being class names to ids of the div since they don't seem to be reused and thus can be a unique identifier for each div. Here is an example of what I mean...

```js
let text = $('#d318 #cell1 .card__text').text().trim()
console.log(text)
//or
$('#output').text(text);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<li id="d318" class="cards__item long">
  <div class="card long">
    <div id="cell0" class="card__content long">
      <p class="card__text">Johnny one</p>
    </div>
    <div id="cell1" class="card__content long">
      <p class="card__text">Rotten one</p>
    </div>
    <div id="cell2" class="card__content long">
      <p class="card__text">One. This was a story of Johnny Rotten</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<div> Results: <span id='output'></span></div>
</body>
</html>
```